# How can I select all the users in my DE that have never received any emails

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can anyone help me with trying to find all the users that have never been sent an email in my De?

Comment: Hi. I recommend you to read this [article](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on the help center which tells you how to ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at some of the documentation on how to appropriately ask a question here, as your question may be closed.  But, to answer your question, the best solution is to use a SQL query against the _Sent Dataview. Quick example below:

```
SELECT de.EmailAddress

FROM myDE as de

INNER JOIN _Sent as s

WHERE de.EmailAddress != s.Subscriberkey
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `on` part of your join.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this.

```
select 
a.emailaddress
, a.subscriberkey
from yourDataExtension a
left join _sent s on s.subscriberkey = a.subscriberkey
where s.subscriberkey is null
```

If the join doesn't yield a match on subscriberkey, then they have not been sent an email in the last 6 months.

**Reference**

- [**System Data Views**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)